# Limits and delta proofs

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have a feeling I'm overthinking the following problem and the associated proof.

There are two parts to this problem.

$i)$ Suppose $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=M$ and $M>0$. Prove there exists $\delta >0$, such that for $0<|x-a|< \delta$ we have $f(x)> \frac{M}{2}$.

$ii)$ Suppose $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=P$ and $P>0$. Prove that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that for
$0<|x-a|< \frac{1}{n}$ we have $|f(x)| \geq \frac{1}{n}$.

For part $i)$, I'm not really sure how to tackle it and it seems to be just the definition of limit.

For part $ii)$, I'm not even sure where to begin for this one.

Can anyone provide some insight on how to handle these two?

Cheers

Comment: $i$) Strictly speaking, this isn't the definition of a limit, but it's certainly closely related. Use the definition to prove the statement. What could you choose for $\varepsilon$? (Also, what happens if $M<0$? Does the statement still hold? What about $M=0$?)

Comment: Well normally you would pick any $\epsilon >0$ and in the case $M=0$ this statement would still hold true I believe.

Comment: For the case $M=0$, consider a function like $f(x)=-x^2$, and take $M=0$. What now?

Comment: As for picking any $\varepsilon > 0$: okay, suppose I pick $\varepsilon = M$. Then the definition of limit says that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, we have $|f(x)-M| < M$. This means that $f(x)$ could be anywhere between $0$ and $2M$, so it isn't guaranteed to be greater than $M/2$.

Comment: Oh okay I understand it now, the idea of using $f(x)=-x^2$ helps a lot to view that. Isn't it true that it doesn't really matter what your $\epsilon$ as I could apply an arbitrary case and use $f(x)$ to be, say between $0$ and $3M$ so than it wouldn't be guaranteed to be greater that $M/3$ in that case.

Comment: The choice of $\varepsilon$ does matter. In the example I gave above, if you choose $\varepsilon = M$, then you are only guaranteeing that $f(x)$ is between $0$ and $2M$. $$0 < f(x) < 2M \require{cancel}\cancel{\implies} f(x) > \frac M2.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, in the $(\epsilon, \delta)$-definition of limit, just set $\epsilon=\frac{M}{2}$ to conclude the statement.

For the second part, first find the least positive integer $N$ such that $N\geq \frac{2}{P}$. Next, using the first part of the problem, find $\delta$, such that for $0<|x-a|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)|\geq f(x)>\frac{P}{2}\geq\frac{1}{N}$. Next, you need to find some $L\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $L\geq \frac{1}{\delta}$ and by setting $n=\max\{L, N\}$ and $0<|x-a|<\frac{1}{n}\leq \delta$, we will have $|f(x)|> \frac{1}{N}\geq\frac{1}{n}$.